# How to print the value for every member of a custom struct in IDA Pro? (In Decompiler mode the members go off screen)

Tags: ida, idapython

In IDA Pro, when you create a custom struct, apply it to a local variable, and try to check every member of it in the decompiler mode, when you hover your mouse on the variable, it only prints limited number of values of struct members based on the screen size, so the rest of them go out of screen:

[image]

How can I view the value of every member of the struct then? When I hover to `field_38` for example, it just prints its offset and doesn't tell me its value.

Using IDA Pro 7.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Locals View](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1518.shtml) in Debugger⇾Debugger Windows⇾Locals window.